# list of reserved variables in mib2c

Tags: perl, mib

Where can I find the list of reserved variable names for mib2c "language"? I mean the possible variables that are not described [here](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/mib2c.conf.html), like ${name}, which evaluates to the OID name that is passed as the argument to mib2c.c.

1. Are there any other variables like that?
2. Is there one that carries the name of the .conf file that was passed to the mib2c.

Comment: @ikegami I agree. The question 3 is created [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45083561/loop-only-though-top-nodes-using-foreach-scalar-in-mib2c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at `local/mib2c` from `net-snmp-5.7.3`, the pre-populated variables are populated by the following code:

```
$outputName = $mibnode->{'label'} if (!defined($outputName));
$outputName =~ s/-/_/g;
$vars{'name'} = $outputName;
$vars{'oid'} = $oid;
$vars{'example_start'} = "    /*\n" .
"    ***************************************************\n" .
"    ***             START EXAMPLE CODE              ***\n" .
"    ***---------------------------------------------***/";
$vars{'example_end'} = "    /*\n" .
"    ***---------------------------------------------***\n" .
"    ***              END  EXAMPLE CODE              ***\n" .
"    ***************************************************/";
```

So, you end up with the following pre-populated variables:

- `$name` is the "output prefix" specified using the `-f` option (or `$mibnode->{'label'}`, whatever that is, if the `-f` option wasn't used), with dashes substituted with underscores.
- `$oid` is the value of `mib2c`'s argument (called "`mibNode`" in the usage help).
- `$example_start` and `$example_end` are hard-coded strings.

That's it.

To create `$config` with the value of the `-c` argument (or `mib2c.conf` if the `-c` option wasn't used), you could alter `mib2c` to add the following to the assignments shown above:

```
$vars{config} = $configfile;
```

Alternatively, I believe the following will also create `$config`, but the value passed to the `-c` option will be prepended with a directory name:

```
@perleval $vars{config} = $configfile; 0@
```

You could try to obtain the original value with the following (which assumes the original value didn't contain a `/`);

```
@perleval $vars{config} = $configfile =~ m{([^/]+)\z}s ? $1 : undef; 0@
```

Completely untested. I don't know anything about SNMP or `mib2c`.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense. It looks like I can not retrieve the value of the configfile argument that is passed with -c option without editing the mib2c file? I can see in the argument parsing portion of the mib2c, the name of the configuration file is assigned to _$configfile_ variable. However, when I use _$configfile_ inside the .config file, the mib2c evaluates it to nothing. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Oh, did not realize that I would put one of the two very last lines with @perleval@ in my .config file. I've got it figured out now!